# .htaccess allow if url contains a word

Tags: .htaccess

I want to allow access to specific domains. For example if domain contains the word asdf it should allow access. I final attempt before asking was:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*asdf.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*1234.*$
#RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

So here I tried to restrict access to all but domains that contain asdf or 1234.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anubhava gave me a clue but not with the http_host. Finally the problem was the OR.
Now the following worked like a charm:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^.*(1234|asdf).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

So HTTP_REFERER did what it should do (check the domain accessing). And the | worked as the or argument I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%{HTTP_HOST}` for checking the domain in URL instead of `%{HTTP_REFERER}`.

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*(asdf|1234)\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: that gave access to everyone

Comment: That's not true actually, it will block any URL that doesn't have `asdf` or `1234` as domain. What URL did you actually try? Also post your latest .htaccess in your question as well.

Comment: thank you for the effort you actually gave me a clue with the or argument and the problem is solved i posted the answer. btw like I said when my .htaccess has exactly what you suggested it allowed access to everyone.

Comment: Glad that you got it working but just understand that HTTP_REFERER represents the domain of the page that refers a user to the current page and HTTP_HOST is the domain of the current URL.